# Robotframework ctrl + space does not work on VS Code

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, robotframework

Hi Does anyone knows how to show the suggested keyword upon pressing ctrl + space on VS Code using Robotframework? Your response is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Pip version I used

[image]

I'm expected once I press ctrl + space it will show available commands.

Comment: Where did you get the info that pressing Ctrl-Space would show suggested keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomiTurtiainen.rf-intellisense which has Code Completion